# How to set an image as background image on top of the div container

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a pattern background which needs to be set on the top of the div which is my container div. I tried by giving the position absolute and top to 0. But the image is not appearing on the top container.
I have attached the fiddle below.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="pattern-top"></div>
        <div>Hello World!</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fcbe07;
  padding: 25px 15px;
}

.pattern-top {
  position: absolute;
  background: ur("https://i.ibb.co/NsQ3tXg/Corner-cover.png") repeat-x 0 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are forgot to add `l` in `background: url("https://i.ibb.co/NsQ3tXg/Corner-cover.png") repeat-x 0 0` and add `height` in class `pattern-top`

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="pattern-top"></div>
        <div>Hello World!</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fcbe07;
  padding: 25px 15px;
  margin-top:30px;
}

.pattern-top {
  position: absolute;
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/NsQ3tXg/Corner-cover.png") repeat-x 0 0;
  top: -25px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Adding a negative in top position, wouldnt it create problem when the browser is resized or in responsive layout ?

Comment: No, it was not created any problem, because you should add top margin in `.container`

Comment: This doesnt work when the image width exceeds 1800px. The pattern to the right is getting hidden..

Comment: Image also loses position when browser resized.

Comment: @tkamath99 why your not use media query in screen resize and first read background property and resolve your problem (for image width exceeds 1800px.). in stackoverflow lot's of answer available for background image.